# .htaccess Redirect ASPX link to new location

Tags: apache, debugging, .htaccess, redirect

Sorry, I'm not very savvy when it comes to `.htaccess` stuff.

I have a legacy link that is

http//mysubdomain.mysite.com/legacy.aspx

how can do  I redirect this link to:

http://mysite.com/newlocation/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file in the root folder of `mysubdomain.mysite.com`

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysubdomain\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^legacy\.aspx$ http://mysite.com/newlocation/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score -2):

You could just use ASP to redirect?
If its only when ppl hit that single page, it should redirect?

```
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location","http://www.new-url.com/"
```

Comment: unfortunately not - the old server was a Windows server, the current one is Linux, so I can't use ASP.

Comment: The legacy.aspx is on a windows server ?
Then you just add the asp redirect to that file?
Then it should redirect to your new linux server just fine...